# TinyMCE custom plugin - Remove / toggle style on second click

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've created a custom style for TinyMCE, which simply wraps some selected content within a div when selected:

```
       ed.focus();
       ed.selection.setContent('<div class="sideContent" role="complimentary">' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</div>');
       ed.undoManager.add();
```

However, once this style has been selected, it can't be removed. Is there a way of making it so that when the button is clicked for a second time, the outer divs are removed?

Thanks in advance.